# In the Windows desktop client of Slack is it possible to change the font of the messages?

Tags: slack

I would like to change the font of the Slack Windows desktop client. Is it possible?

I have searched the registry, also checked the files which are located in the folder

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\slack

without finding any place to change it.

(I would even considering remapping the font it uses to something else, but I don't know which font it is using).

Update: What I have figured out that the Slack client has an embedded Chrome browser and the page is using a web font Alto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can now be done with the `/slackfont` command:
e.g. `/slackfont Times New Roman`

Comment: could you enhance your answer with more changes? (a) how to reset the default : `/slackfont`<kbd>return</kbd>  (b) how to change font weight (?) and (c) size https://slack.com/intl/en-gb/help/articles/236067467-Adjust-your-zoom-level-in-Slack

Answer (score 3):

There was a discussion on Twitter with the Slack developers about being able to change fonts for accessibility reasons: https://twitter.com/manchicken/status/718501914661548032.

Unfortunately, changing the font (other than switching to the built-in compact theme) is not a feature.

Comment: Tweet doesn't exist anymore

Comment: It appears to still exist on my end, but the direct response from Slack's twitter was "It's not possible at the moment, but it's something we're actively looking into. Stay tuned!" This was up to date in mid-2016 and appears to still apply now.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font of Slack in Chrome by changing the font there. Background: Slack uses build in chrome browser to display the slack content

Comment: how do you that? Do you need to install Chrome?

Answer (score -1):

You can adjust the zoom level in slack, which gives a similar effect. Ctrl + and Ctrl - adjust the zoom level.

https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/236067467-Adjust-your-zoom-level-in-Slack

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DonaldDuck If you look right above the link in my answer, I do explain how to adjust the zoom level. I did not provide a link only answer.

Comment: They don't ask how to change the font size. They ask how to change the font.

Comment: I was actually looking for increasing the font size and this answer worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: The OP didn't specify if they wanted to change size, family or weight, so I upvoted this answer. Font size also shows up, named 'Zoom', in the Accessibility section of the Preferences pane. Surprisingly I can't zoom with the mouse wheel.